# How to order week or month wise in sequelize PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, count, include, sequelize.js

How to count them and display on a weekly basis or monthly basis?

here is the query :

```
Company.findAll({
    attributes: [
        'id', 'title', 'is_enabled',
        [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('company_users.id')) ,'user_count'] // <---- Here you will get the total count of user
    ],
    include: [
        {
            model: sqConn.CompanyUser,
            attributes: [] // <----- Make sure , this should be empty
        }
    ],
    group: ['companies.id'] // <---- You might require this one also
}).then(data => { 
    console.log(data); // <---- Check the output
})
```

expected output:
company details along with

> 1.no of company users registered every month in the count.
>
> 2.year and month

```
"company": "data",
"company_user": [
  {
    "month": 2,
    "year": 2017,  
    "count": 2
  }, {
    "month": 3,
    "year": 2018,
    "count": 22  // number of company users registered in march 2018
  }, {...}
]
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want your output to look like?

Comment: @Rastalamm Updated my expected output please check

Comment: Does this all have to happen during the query? Can you first do a query that gets the info, and then look through the response and build the output you are looking for?